# col.xs in bootstrap being set on table with 800 resolution

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am messing around learning bootstrap at the moment and I seem to have an issue with the columns.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
      <p>Test</p>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
      <p>Test</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
      <p>Test</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
      <p>Test</p>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have set all the others to be 1 wide but the xs is set to 3.  The issue I have it seems to be setting my Galaxy tab 4 to the sx setting even though the resolution for it on the official tech specs is 1280 x 800 (WXGA).

I have checked the css and I have zero custom css's set.  Can anyone explain or suggest why its doing this?

Comment: In messing around with the css, I have to take col.sm down to 601px to get it to show on a 1280 x 800 resolution, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have ordering issue as lg=large, md=medium, xs=extra small .replace this may help you.

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3">
```

to

```
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-3">
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the order from small to large but still it is using the xs on the tablet and not sm,

Comment: The css is the standard one from bootstraps site, so there is next to nothing in, just the menu bar.